# Strange numpy issubdtype behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am iterating on a file containing 3.3 million rows to check for datatype of that column and perform action based on if it contains integer or not.

While that cell value like a55950602, a92300416  is easily recognized as False for issubdtype as np.integer, it fails in case of ga99266e.

Code:
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import time
    import math

```
start_time = time.time()
lstNumberCounts = []
lstIllFormed = []

dfClicks = pd.read_csv('Oct3_distinct_Members.csv')
dfClicks['UNIV_MBR_ID'] = dfClicks['UNIV_MBR_ID'].str.split('-').str[0]
dfClicks['UNIV_MBR_ID'] = dfClicks['UNIV_MBR_ID'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore')

for item in dfClicks['UNIV_MBR_ID']:
    if (np.issubdtype(item,np.integer)):
        lstNumberCounts.append(math.floor(math.log10(item))+1)
else:
    lstIllFormed.append(item)


print("---Processing Time: %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Code runs well for above mentioned values but one which throws error on console as below:
    TypeError: data type "ga99266e" not understood

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html that should help already

Comment: Sorry, but what should I be looking for in that link. I am self learner in python and recently started working on it to automate

Comment: errors='ignore' makes pd.to_numeric either return a numeric value (which then tests True for issubdtype(...,integer)) or the input. The input is then "ga99266e" if that can't be converted to numeric. I don't know what type that then has, but apparently  np.issubdtype knows neither. You can use 'coerce' instead of 'ignore' and then testing if it is NaN if you don't need the other fields, or you need to do some different parsing.

Comment: Understood. But it correctly processed "a55950602" which is a string to else part of the code. I am curious about whats so specific about "ga99266e".

Comment: I've added that to my answer. Interesting behaviour indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore'` [returns either a numeric value or the input](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html). So in case of "ga99266e" it returns "ga99266e" which is a string. If you feed numpys issubdtype a string, [it checks if the string is the name of a dtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.issubdtype.html). (Eg. np.issubdtype('int',int) returns True).

So you need to first check if your field is still a string and then if not you can check if it's a numpy integer.

Try:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import time 
import math
start_time = time.time()
lstNumberCounts = []
lstIllFormed = []

dfClicks = pd.read_csv('Oct3_distinct_Members.csv')
dfClicks['UNIV_MBR_ID'] = dfClicks['UNIV_MBR_ID'].str.split('-').str[0]
dfClicks['UNIV_MBR_ID'] = dfClicks['UNIV_MBR_ID'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore')

for item in dfClicks['UNIV_MBR_ID']:
    if not (isinstance(item,str)):
        if (np.issubdtype(item,np.integer)):
            lstNumberCounts.append(math.floor(math.log10(item))+1)
    else:
        lstIllFormed.append(item)


print("---Processing Time: %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

---

"a123456" or any string starting with "a" works with `np.issubdtype`, because numpy interprets it as a code telling it what type of number the following number is. [See:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

> Array-protocol type strings (see The Array Interface)
>
> The first character specifies the kind of data and the remaining characters specify the number of bytes per item, except for Unicode, where it is interpreted as the number of characters. The item size must correspond to an existing type, or an error will be raised. The supported kinds are
>
> '?'    boolean
>
> 'b'    (signed) byte
>
> 'B'    unsigned byte
>
> 'i'    (signed) integer
>
> 'u'    unsigned integer
>
> 'f'    floating-point
>
> 'c'    complex-floating point
>
> 'm'    timedelta
>
> 'M'    datetime
>
> 'O'    (Python) objects
>
> 'S', **'a'**   zero-terminated bytes (not recommended)
>
> 'U'    Unicode string
>
> 'V'    raw data (void)